# excel to json in php

Tags: php, json, excel

I am just learning to code, i dont know much yet.

```html
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";
  $tmpfname = "tabula1.xlsx";
  $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
  $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
  $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);//
  $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
  
  echo "<table>";
  for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();
    echo "</td><tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>"; 
  

</body>
</html>
```

here's my code. I need to output the data in json from excel table. I have been searching for solution in youtube and google, but i have found nothing i understand so far. What should i write, what should i do? Also, i got this code from this forum and i edited it so it works for me. I would  be very grateful if someone could help me with this <3

Comment: That's not bad for a start. Instead of dumping your excel data to HTML, you should store them in a plain array and then use `json_serialize` to create your JSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this, using your loop to create an array and the `json_encode` to convert it to a json string:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";
        $tmpfname = "tabula1.xlsx";
        $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
        $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
        $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);//
        $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

        $data = [];
        for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
             $data[] = [
                'A' => $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue(),
                'B' => $worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue()
             ];
        }

echo json_encode($data);

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where can I download `PHPExcel.php`

Comment: @151291 you can download here https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel, but now it's marked as deprecated. You should use https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: Yep, I am using `PhpSpreadsheet` and got the solution, https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ it's cool and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Only logic not tested

```
 $result=array();
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) 
    {           
    array_push($result,array($worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue(),$worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue()));
        }

    echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

```
<?php

require(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/export_import/vendor/autoload.php');

        $inputFileName = __DIR__ . '/1.xlsx';
        $inputFileType = 'Xlsx';

        /**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
        $reader = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        /**  Advise the Reader that we only want to load cell data  **/
        $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        /**  Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
        $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
        $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet(0);//
        // Get the highest row and column numbers referenced in the worksheet
        $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
        $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
        $highestColumnIndex = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

        $data = array();
        for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
            $riga = array();
            for ($col = 1; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; $col++) {
                $riga[] = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
            }
            if (1 === $row) {
                // Header row. Save it in "$keys".
                $keys = $riga;
                continue;
            }
            $data[] = array_combine($keys, $riga);
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        print json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    $full_path = "file.xlsx";

    $characters = array();
    for ($i = 65; $i <= 90; $i++) {
        $characters[] = chr($i);
    }


    $inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
    $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $reader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);


    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($full_path);
    $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getSheet(0);//
    $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();



    $data = [];
    $headers = array();
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
        
        if ($row == 1) {
            foreach ($characters as $c) {
                if ($worksheet->getCell($c . $row) and strlen($worksheet->getCell($c . $row)->getValue()) > 0) {
                    $headers[$c] = $worksheet->getCell($c . $row)->getValue();
                }
            }
        }else{
            foreach ($characters as $c) {
                if ($worksheet->getCell($c . $row) and strlen($worksheet->getCell($c . $row)->getValue()) > 0) {
                    $data[$headers[$c]] = $worksheet->getCell($c . $row)->getValue();
                }
            }
            
        }
    }


    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;

?>
```